# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 automatically install the .NET Framework by default?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does SQL Server 2008 R2 automatically install the .NET Framework by default? If so, which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does, if it isn't already installed. The version is 3.5 SP1. [See the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx) for details.